# Create instance via a has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, model-associations

I knew this a few days ago!

`discussion` has many `discussion_replies` and many `replies` through `discussion_replies`

`discussion_replies` belongs_to `discussion` and belongs_to `reply`

`reply` has_many `discussion_replies` and many `discussions` through `discussion_replies`

Now, on the rails console, what is the best way to create a reply to a discussion?

This does not work:

```
var_discussion.discussion_replies.create_reply()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this, I'm giving you an example. It will work for sure

```
discussion = Discussion.first
discussion.replies.create(#reply_attributes)
```

This will automatically create entries in `discussion_replies` table